# Azure DevOps PR message - "Work items only from the first 100 commits will be linked"?

Tags: git, azure-devops, pull-request

Thank you for any definition of what "only from the first 100 commits will be linked" means.

Will I lose commits if I complete the Pull request ( PR )?

> This pull request will merge over 100 commits into master. Double
> check the source and target branches to make sure this is intentional.
> Work items only from the first 100 commits will be linked.

[image]

I made my dev branch from main and made too many commits before trying to do a Pull request (PR). My bad.

Thank you for any definition of what "only from the first 100 commits will be linked".

Comment: Hi, have you ever checked my answer and see whether it helps?

Answer (score 2):

I have created 103 commits with each commit the same WIT1 linked, firstly, I can also meet the same warning tips as your side. But **this warning message will not affect your completing on merge PR behavior.**

Then after PR completed, when I check in the WIT1, it can be shown with the first 100 commits, the commits of over 100 times will not be shown in the WIT1.

**Step1**: Created 103 commits with each commit the same WIT1 linked.

[image]
Step2: After PR completed, when checking in the WIT1, it can be shown with the first 100 commits, the commits of over 100 times will not be shown in the WIT1.

[image]

So, by the test above, it will not lose the commits after completing the PR, and in WIT it will shown the first 100 commits,  over 100 commits will not be shown, but they are not lost, you also still can check all the commits via **Specified Repo -> Branches**.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This *notice* message refers to the linked work items per commit and not to the code in the commits.

So you don‘t lose any code or commits. You will only see the last 100 linked work item per commit in this pull request.

I would recommend that you create a pull request more often, then you will never encounter this message again!

Comment: A "work item" is a bug report/task issue and the warning is talking about git commits linked to Azure DevOps "work items"?  We use JIRA.  It sounds like the ominous warning "Work items only from the first 100 commits will be linked" has zero consequences if you are not using Azure DevOps "work items" as your issue tracker?