# Is there a limit on number of commits in a single PR for Microsoft DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, commit, azure-synapse, pull-request

I am working with MS Azure Synapse Analytics (in MS DevOps) and received [this warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6dP4.png) when sending a Pull request:

This is not an error (I am still able to send the PR), but I was wondering if there is a limit on number of commits in a single PR, for MS DevOps?

Note: I am not asking about the number of objects committed, but the number of total commits.

Thanks

Comment: There isn't a limit for a regular merge, but for the 2 rebase merge types there is a limit. I know the rebase limit used to be 25 commits, but it may have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no explicit commit number limit in pull request. The waring will not affect the merge result once PR completed.

I used local bash script to create 310 commits on dev branch, when creating PR to main branch, it has same warning with you.

```
for i in `seq 1 310`; 
do
    echo $i >> README.md
    git add .
    git commit -m "change $i"
    git push
done
```

[image]

Once PR completed, the code is merged.
[image]

But it's not recommended to have some many commits in one Pull request, for best practice to use less commits, this helps to ensure a high quality of code review and avoid cognitive overload for the reviewers.

You can also find similar answer in ticket [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74407095/azure-devops-pr-message-work-items-only-from-the-first-100-commits-will-be-li#:%7E:text=This%20notice%20message%20refers%20to%20the%20linked%20work,then%20you%20will%20never%20encounter%20this%20message%20again%21).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know it's not "recommended", but it's the only way to save your work if you're working directly in Azure Portal (I'm not using Visual Studio, for example)... So, I'll probably need thousands of commits :)